# Installing Samba from Source and Receiving Gnutls Error

Tags: apt, samba, gnutls

OK, after beating my head against the wall for a day I need help trying to figure out what's going on here:

```
Using in-tree heimdal kerberos defines
Checking for program krb5-config.heimdal                                          : not found
Checking for program krb5-config                                                  : not found
Checking for gnutls >= 3.4.7                                                      : not found
Checking for gnutls >= 3.0.0s                                                     : not found
Checking for gnutls >= 1.4.0 and broken versions                                  : not found
/linux1/tmp/samba-4.6.2/source4/lib/tls/wscript:51: error: Building the AD DC requires GnuTLS (eg libgnutls-dev, gnutls-devel) for ldaps:// support and for the BackupKey protocol
root@blahblahblah:/linux1/tmp/samba-4.6.2# apt-get install libgnutls-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libgnutls-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@blahblahblah:/linux1/tmp/samba-4.6.2#
```

I am trying to install Samba from source and when I do ./configure it's telling me that it can't find libgnutls-dev, even though I've installed several variations of this package with apt-get.

Looking through the ./configure -h has not be -h-ful.

Comment: You will have to file a bug report with samba

Comment: How exactly have you "installed several variations of" libgnutls-dev? what do `pkg-config --modversion gnutls` and `pkg-config --variable=prefix gnutls` say?

Comment: Ah ha... that's it. thanks @steeldriver, I really appreciate your help these past few days!!

They both say:

"Package gnutls was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gnutls.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gnutls' found"

I think I can figure that out from here...

Comment: Note that **unless you messed with the `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` variable**, `pkg-config` has a default search path that includes all the places that `apt-get` / `dpkg` would put the `.pc` file - so it strongly suggests you do not currently have a version of `libgnutls-dev` installed via `apt-get` (or have manually moved or deleted the `.pc` file since installing).

Comment: @steeldriver Well, again, I am using my own version of pkg-config built from source in the /linux1 directory. So, I'm guessing that I should have waited to build pkg-config until the very end

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to run before you can walk - if you have built pkg-config with a non-standard search path (check the path with `pkg-config --variable=pc_path pkg-config`) then you may be able to use `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to prepend a sensible default list of system directories in the meantime. Or install the default version of `pkgconfig` from the repository and make sure that it is ahead of your source-built version on your `PATH`

Comment: You're telling me. It's a requirement for my new job; so, kinda just gotta do it... but thanks for the help.